# Rotating line with pythagoras formula

Tags: vb.net

I want to rotate a line but i don't want to use radians or pi.I created an algorithm (if i can call  it like that).I use pythagoras formula with two functions and two timers to rotate the line ,but i think there's an error because it rotate faster after 180 degrees rotation.Why?Here's my code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Structure poi
    Dim x As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
End Structure

Dim x1 As Integer, y1 As Integer
Dim x As Integer, y As Integer
Dim val As Integer
Dim obxy As poi
Dim moupos As poi
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Call calcxy(val, 100)

    x = obxy.x
    y = obxy.y
    val = val - 1

    Refresh()
    If -val > 100 Then
        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer2.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If Button1.Text = "Start" Then
        Timer1.Enabled = True
        Button1.Text = "Stop"
    Else

        Timer1.Enabled = False
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        Button1.Text = "Start"
    End If

End Sub

Sub calcxy(choice As Integer, radius As Integer)
    Dim yval As Integer
    yval = Math.Sqrt(radius ^ 2 - choice ^ 2)

    obxy.x = moupos.x - choice
    obxy.y = moupos.y - yval
End Sub
Sub recalcxy(choice As Integer, radius As Integer)
    Dim yval As Integer
    yval = Math.Sqrt(radius ^ 2 - choice ^ 2)

    obxy.x = moupos.x - choice
    obxy.y = moupos.y + yval
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_MouseClick(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    moupos.x = e.X
    moupos.y = e.Y
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
    Dim pen As New System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Color.Black, 1)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, moupos.x, moupos.y, x, y)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    val = 100
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    val = val + 1

    Call recalcxy(val, 100)

    x = obxy.x
    y = obxy.y
    Refresh()
    If val + 1 > 100 Then
        Timer2.Enabled = False
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: That is not VBScript.

Comment: It is due to the handoff from one timer to the next and val not being changed correctly. Put a label on your form and watch val carefully as it goes around the circle, and you'll see it do weird things around the 180 mark.Also increase the time in your timer interval so you can see it better. My suggestion is to have just one timer with both sets of logic so you can keep track of the values better.